# Is there a way to use Frida or any other tool to invoke a method in an IOS application with your own argument?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, frida

Is there a way, maybe a script or API to invoke a method in an IOS application without manually triggering it on the application itself and also replacing the values? The goal for this is to make sure that the query from a server will return the values that I want.

Example:
If the value 1 is sent to the server, it return will back "True", but I want the return value to be "False", so I need to invoke the method that queries the server and change the argument value to 0. Can frida force activate a method without interaction or is there another tool that can perform this?

Comment: First if you have a method that is called to retrieve a value from a server why don't you hook it and simple overwrite the return value in `onLeave`? But your question continues and it is getting a bit confused because some times you are talking about parameters that you want to change and then you are talking about the return value.

Comment: Oh because let's say i don't have access to a server but I want to get data out of its database. So my thought process would be to run a query function in the application to return back values. For example, a function that takes in a userid and returns back a score, I want to specifically target user1 which is why overwriting `onLeave` wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to intercept all function calls in order to alter the return value, read up on the basic interception functionality using Interceptor.attach

If you want to instantiate your own or an existing object, look at the following examples:
https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/567#issuecomment-406897414

Comment: Do I instantiate an existing object in the handler js files created from frida-trace or create my own js script and run it with frida?